# ¿Como hacer una condicional if dependiendo de que tipo modelo contenga mi variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo la siguiente el siguiente codigo

```
var response = await ...
```

el `response` del `await` puede ser de dos tipos, por ejemplo de tipo Modelo1 o de tipo Modelo2 dependiendo de que tipo modelo sea la respuesta necesito hacer ciertas cosas, es aquí como no se si es que existe algo en c# para poder decir si la variable `response` contiene o tiene un modelo de tipo `Modelo1` que haga esto o sino que haga esto otro.

Comment: Bro, os invoco en la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Todo lo que hiciste de bien con los generics, lo arruinaste aca :(

Comment: Si vas a hacer el if aca.. que sentido tenia el metodo generico? terminas haciendo justamente lo que querias evitar en la otra pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta, puedes utilizar `typeof` y `GetType()`

Deberías usarlo así

```
var response = await ....   
if(response != null)
{
    if(typeof(Modelo1) == response.GetType())
    {
    //Lógica si es Modelo1
    }
else
    {
      //Lógica si es Modelo2 u cualquier otro Objeto
    }
}
```

Perdón si hay algún error de sintaxis pero no tengo IDE a mano, espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos!

Comment: Gracias me sirvio (:

Answer (score 0):

Crea una clase genérica, esta es la que yo uso:

```
public interface ITypeOf<T>
{
    T Value {get;}
}

public abstract class TypeOf<T1, T2>
{
    private TypeOf() {}

    public static TypeOf<T1, T2> Type1(T1 value) =>
        new Type1(value);

   public static TypeOf<T1, T2> Type2(T2 value) =>
       new Type2(value);

    public abstract bool IsType1 { get; }
    public abstract bool IsType2 { get; }
    public abstract TResult Switch<TResult>(Func<T1, TResult> isType1, Func<T2, TResult> isType2);

   private static class Types
   {
       public class Type1 : TypeOf<T1, T2>, ITypeOf<T1>
       {
           public Type1(T1 value)
           {
               Value = value;
           }

           public T1 Value {get;}
           public override bool IsType1 => true;
           public override bool IsType2 => false;
           public override TResult Switch<TResult>(Func<T1, TResult> isType1, Func<T2, TResult> isType2) =>
               isType1(Value);
       }

       public class Type2 : TypeOf<T1, T2>, ITypeOf<T2>
       {
           public Type2(T2 value)
           {
               Value = value;
           }

           public T2 Value {get;}
           public override bool IsType1 => false;
           public override bool IsType2 => true;
           public override TResult Switch<TResult>(Func<T1, TResult> isType1, Func<T2, TResult> isType2) =>
               isType2(Value);
       }
    }
}
```

Y para usarla:

```
public string GetResult(TypeOf<string, int> value)
{
    if (value.IsType1) // evitamos un casteo innecesario
    {
        var result = value as ITypeOf<string>;
        return $"El resultado es string: {result.Value}"; // la propiedad Value es de tipo string
    }
   else
   {
       var result = value as ITypeOf<int>;
       return $"El resultado es int: {result.Value}"; // la propiedad Value es de tipo int
    }

    // con c# 7:
    // if (value is IType<string> result) 
    // {
    //      return $"El res.....: {result.Value}";
    // }
}
```

O utilizando el método switch:

```
public string GetResult(TypeOf<string, int> value)
{
    return value.Switch(
        isType1: s => $"El resultado es string: {s}", // en esta función lambda, s es de tipo string
        isType2: i => $"El resultado es int: {i}); // en esta función lambda, i es de tipo int
}
```

Y así creas el objeto:

```
var opcion1 = TypeOf<string, int>.Type1("hola");
var opcion2 = TypeOf<string, int>.Type2(3);

var x = GetResult(opcion1); // x debería ser igual a "El resultado es string: hola"
var y = GetResult(opcion2); // y debería ser igual a "El resultado es int: 3"
```